# Errors when passing extras with intent in android development

Tags: android, android-intent, fatal-error

I am trying to send a username from one activity to another. I have the following code in the first activity:

```
    etUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username);
    Intent parent = new Intent(Login.this, Parent_Home.class);
    parent.putExtra("username", etUsername.getText().toString());
    startActivity(parent);
```

And then try to retrieve it in the second activity as follows:

```
   Button bChild, bChore, bRewards, bStats, bSettings;
   Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
   String user = extras.getString("username");
```

However when I run this the application crashes and I get the following error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                               Process: com.jack.pointcollector, PID: 13980
                                               java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.jack.pointcollector/com.jack.pointcollector.Parent_Home}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.os.Bundle android.content.Intent.getExtras()' on a null object reference
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2327)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.os.Bundle android.content.Intent.getExtras()' on a null object reference
                                                   at com.jack.pointcollector.Parent_Home.<init>(Parent_Home.java:11)
                                                   at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
                                                   at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1067)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2317)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Any ideas what is causing this?

Comment: In which call back you're trying to retrieve username?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `getIntent()` on a field initializer. Do not do this. Do not call `getIntent()` — or pretty much any method on your activity — until after you have called `super.onCreate()` in your `onCreate()` method of your activity.

In [this sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Activities/Extras), my launcher activity packages an extra in the `Intent` it uses to start another activity:

```
/***
  Copyright (c) 2012 CommonsWare, LLC
  Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License"); you may not
  use this file except in compliance with the License. You may obtain a copy
  of the License at http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0. Unless required
  by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software distributed under the
  License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS
  OF ANY KIND, either express or implied. See the License for the specific
  language governing permissions and limitations under the License.

  From _The Busy Coder's Guide to Android Development_
    https://commonsware.com/Android
*/

package com.commonsware.android.extra;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

public class ExtrasDemoActivity extends Activity {
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
  }

  public void showOther(View v) {
    Intent other=new Intent(this, OtherActivity.class);

    other.putExtra(OtherActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE, getString(R.string.other));
    startActivity(other);
  }
}
```

I then retrieve and use that value in `OtherActivity`... but not until inside `onCreate()`:

```
/***
  Copyright (c) 2012 CommonsWare, LLC
  Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License"); you may not
  use this file except in compliance with the License. You may obtain a copy
  of the License at http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0. Unless required
  by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software distributed under the
  License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS
  OF ANY KIND, either express or implied. See the License for the specific
  language governing permissions and limitations under the License.

  From _The Busy Coder's Guide to Android Development_
    https://commonsware.com/Android
*/

package com.commonsware.android.extra;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class OtherActivity extends Activity {
  public static final String EXTRA_MESSAGE="msg";

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.other);

    TextView tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.msg);

    tv.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE));
  }
}
```